# Extracting sublink in between two characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I extract a sub-link between two characters in a string?

For example, I'd like to extract the Video ID in a youtube URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u
```

I'd like the text between the "`=`" and the first "`&`" sign, which would be "`UkzbRkPv4T4`".

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/1wNZ92bTpZ

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to deal with regular expressions, you could rely on functionality from Ruby's Standard Library for parsing URLs:

```
url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u"
video_id = CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)['v'][0]
```

Comment: +1 It's good to take advantage of the tools created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a regular expression:

```
uri = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u'
m = uri.match /v=(?<id>\w+)&/
if m
  puts m[:id]
end
```

Comment: trying to do the following:

'<% m = post.link.match /v=(?<id>\w+)&/ %>
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= m[0] %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

But I get the following error:

**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: @dkind: `m[0]` will print out the whole match, not the group, which would be `m[:id]`. What does `<%= post.link %>` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon apneadiving's comment.

```
>> url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u"
=> "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u"
>> md = url.match(/v=(.*)&/)
=> #<MatchData "v=UkzbRkPv4T4&" 1:"UkzbRkPv4T4">
>> md[1]
=> "UkzbRkPv4T4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u")
uri.query
# => "v=UkzbRkPv4T4&feature=g-all-u"
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)
# => [["v", "UkzbRkPv4T4"], ["feature", "g-all-u"]]
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).map(&:last)
# => ["UkzbRkPv4T4", "g-all-u"]
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).assoc("v").last
# => "UkzbRkPv4T4"
```